# Yodlee FastLink Hide List of Added Accounts

Tags: yodlee

Is it possible to hide the list of added accounts (and also the "show all added accounts" link at the bottom) in Yodlee FastLink ([see first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMkZA.jpg)).

I'd also like to keep the help text on the next screen visible ([see second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQoeu.jpg)).  Looking at the HTML/CSS of the page I am not sure if this is possible.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible.
Once you'll become Yodlee's customer and have your own staging environment, you can ask Yodlee support team to disable this for you.

Also, the Fastlink version you are looking is an older version. Yodlee has introduced the latest version [Fastlink 2.0](https://developer.yodlee.com/Fastlink_2.0), this has additional features in comparison to Fastlink 1.0.